# Drop Shadow Effect "размывает" текст

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть текст к которому хочется добавить тень. Я применяю к тексту следующий эффект:

```
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="0" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
```

Но после добавления эффекта появляется неприятный эффект, а именно: Текст "размывается" (так как будто бы вместе с DropShadowEffect добавляется ещё и BlurEffect ): 
[image: Пример текста без эффекта и с эффектом]

Эффект размытия не сильный, но всё же заметный глазу.

Возможно ли от него избавиться или каким-либо другим способом добавить тень к тексту?

Comment: попробуйте в конструкторе окна(пользовательского элемента) в начале добавить **TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextOptions - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.textoptions(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<TextBlock Text="ТЕКСТ" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
  <TextBlock.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="0" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
  </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

или в коде

```
TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(textBlock1, TextFormattingMode.Display);
```